# Failed to access chromadb from django app with docker compose, HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8989): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: django, docker-compose, chromadb

I am trying to build a REST api with django and chromadb, I built two containers: django for RESTApi, chroma for vector database. Two containers are running successfully. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  django:
    container_name: django
    build:
      context: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/Users/apple/Docker/app/
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    expose:
      - 8000
  chroma:
    container_name: chroma
    image: ghcr.io/chroma-core/chroma:latest
    volumes:
      - index_data:/Users/apple/Docker/app/data
    ports:
      - '8989:8989'
    expose:
      - 8989
volumes:
  index_data:
    name: my-db-data
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /Users/apple/Docker/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /Users/apple/Docker/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /Users/apple/Docker/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /Users/apple/Docker/app/

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/Users/apple/Docker/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I am trying to establish a connect from django to chromadb, as following:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings
chroma_client = chromadb.HttpClient(
    host='localhost',
    port=8989,
    settings=Settings(allow_reset=True, anonymized_telemetry=False))


@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    sample_collection = chroma_client.get_or_create_collection(name="sample_collection")
    print(sample_collection)
    return Response({
        'info': 'Hello world.'
    })
```

I got this error message:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8989): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/collections (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f35e0e3c4f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Here is the docker containers:

```
CONTAINER ID    PORTS.                              NAMES 
2710918946b0    0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              django 
18ee5e4e3a7d    8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8989->8989/tcp    chroma
```

I did some research, it seems like the problem of port conflict, I try change the port, but I still did not work. Please help me, I really appreciate.

Comment: First think i noticed in your code is that as per the chroma docs, you need clickhouse dependency to run with chroma. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617149/6697622

Comment: it seems like you cannot connect because chroma is not up and running as chroma cannot find clickhouse